# Create a Service with Java that runs when the app is deoployed ?

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, service, websphere, vs-web-application-project

I have a Web Application with J2EE and Spring, related to an Oracle 10g Database. I want to create a Service in Java that will poll statistics from the Database and send mail every 5 min. This Service should start when the application is deployed under Tomcat or Web-sphere.
Any Ideas How this could be done ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since use Spring, its [Time execution and scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) classes seem a natural choice. They work both in Tomcat and Websphere, just create your task as a POJO and schedule it:

```xml
<bean id="PollingTask" class="com.sth.PollingPOJO">
         <!-- properties, if any -->
</bean>

<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1" />

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <!-- runs every 30 minutes -->
    <task:scheduled ref="PollingTask" method="run" fixed-delay="#{ 30*60*1000 }" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

The `PollingTask` looks like (note that it doesn't have to implement `Runnable`, "run" method is just a convention):

```java
class PollingTask() {
    public void run() {
        // entry point
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion, i will try to use this. And test it in my application.